# All funds for SCIENCE!

Tags: technology

A certain event has happened and the governments of the world decided they needed to research everything.
And so, the whole world suddenly started to focus on science.

All unnecessary funds like the army + all the man power from there. All the corporations around the world forget about the profit and want to advance mankind.

Schools start to focus more on that and children are encouraged to become scientist and develop all kinds of new technologies instead of going for profitable jobs.

USA military budget for 2015 was 598.5 billion dollars, yet something like the Large Hadron Collider only costed 8.4 billion US dollars is founded by a whole lot of countries and took so much time to make...

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶d̶e̶a̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶f̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶w̶e̶ ̶g̶o̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶a̶d̶v̶a̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶r̶a̶c̶e̶?̶ ̶W̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶h̶a̶p̶p̶e̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶c̶e̶n̶a̶r̶i̶o̶?̶ ̶

How long until we pass the point where we can no longer get extinct, at least on a planetary scale?

P.S not sure if this is a the proper StackExchange for a question like this?

Comment: It would be a real nice world

Comment: We typically frown on what-if style questions that are so open ended: 'http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask'. Try to add more constraints such as 'In a world where all funds were given to scientivic endevour, what would be the economical effects' as an example.

Comment: @Sky It would be a *horrible* world.

Comment: @NexTerren I was sarcastic. Though is having a peaceful world really just a pipe dream? I haven't lost all my hope yet.

Comment: @Sky I'm for peace, just not zombies. Achieving perfect peace--*perfect*--implies something fundamentally changed in our mental makeup to make us unable to have conflict, or some external dictatorial force. Neither are ideas that I like.

Comment: @NexTerren True, though I always feel sad for the saints(peace-lovers) that are usually harshly criticized by the protagonist.

Comment: Seems very broad, on the no longer go extinct question, maybe pick some specific area to focus on.  Focusing on science might also not be the best strategy to avoid extinction, there are some methods of planetary extinction that would require vast resources and technology, not knowledge, to combat effectively.  Kind of like the distinction between science and engineering, knowing something is theoretically possible and being able to do it are not the same thing.

Comment: I kind of place them in the same broad category. Isn't engineering part of science?

Comment: @STARGATEBG Technically engineering is creating/designing tools and other objects  from the application of science, and science is the peer-reviewed repeatable documentation of... well... reality. But you're absolutely right that in common use engineering is a subset of science.

Comment: The humans will no longer be able to become extinct in a few hundred years, because they have already gone extinct - in blood and terror.  Because science is amoral - that is, the advance of science can be done equally well by peaceful means or terrible ones, and "not caring" about "unnecessary" things also means not caring about the things that have us choose peaceful ways.  Because some of those advances will be terrible things, with terrible (unforeseen) effects.  Because some of those things people suddenly can no longer care about are needed for survival, reproduction, self-preservation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So:

The entire population of Earth loses all sense of free will, and become zombies with the singular focus of scientific advancement. Any aspect of the human mind that would possibly drive someone to do anything *but* the advancement of science is purged from the mind. War isn't even a consideration, because the people of Earth couldn't possibly fight because their entire focus is *science.*

How far, and how fast would we advance?

We have absolutely no way of knowing.

No, seriously. Even the concept of "all funds to science" goes out the window, since money has no place in our world; individual motivations and competition are both gone, and people can't be lazy or unmotivated. As a side note, those who cost more resources than they produce for science will not be euthanized, since we're devoting 100% of our efforts to *science.* Resources to keep the elderly or mentally deficient alive are 'unnecessary,' after all.

Capitalist society would vanish (as the need for it would as well, as we have morally uncompromisable beings wandering around), and governments devolve into little more than logistical centers. Art would be purged except where it could be justified that it expands creativity of science (most movie studios would shut down, most creative writers would be repurposed...). Concepts of religion, social connection, races, social policies have all gone out the window (after all, we're in a world where there's nothing that *possibly* could drive us to war), and we find ourselves in a world *so entirely different* from the civilization we know today that drawing a comparison even foundationally is difficult to do.

Comment: sounds like the [Vulcans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_(Star_Trek))

Answer (score 1):

I think this idea was addressed in the movie [**Tomorrowland**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1964418/). And since I don't want to add any spoilers I'll just say that: In theory anything can sound like a great idea.

If all of the military funding was shifted to research and development this would effectively end the military. To some people this sounds like a good thing, but it would never work because there is Evil in the world. If the United States dismantled its military and certain countries in the middle east didn't dismantle their military, we would be a sitting duck. If someone attacked how would we defend ourselves?

Also remember that most of the world's greatest advancements were because of war. Our knowledge of Sub-atomic physics, Jet Engines, Radar and even some medicines are a direct result of war. Don't get me wrong, war is not a good thing but it has a side-effect that causes humanity to innovate out of necessity.

Comment: I'm talking about all the countries in the world, and I know a lot of things came because of war but they can also be researched independently. And you don't need such a massive army if you are not going against other countries.

Comment: Sorry, I started writing my answer before the last edit

Comment: we happened to make those advancements in war because the necessity was surviving/winning  the war.The motivation here could be money since our income is driven to a subject where the most educated would receive the highest income not just the innovators. motivation is what we need for accomplishments and our history just happens to coincide with discoveries during war. the military might have been a controversial point but i see where u are coming from with your point on removing funds from other large organisations

Comment: My bad for not writing the proper question in one go :)